# Can you call java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.release() on a different thread you did acquire() on?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a java module which requires doing a set of tasks concurrently through interfaces (to give low-level control and handling to frameworks implementing the module), but not too many at the same time, `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` seems perfect for this.

The one problem I'm not certain about is thread safety of `release()` and `acquire()` calls. Can one thread acquire semaphore locks, and later another thread release it?

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing to stop you doing that. It would be a very weird (i.e. bad) implementation. You should only release what you have previously acquired.

Comment: why not try it yourself? If it doesn't work java will surely complain with an Exception or an Error

Comment: @Michael - That is an overstatement.  The OP's code will certainly be simpler and easier to reason about if responsibility for "releasing" is not passed from one thread to another.  But it is only (clearly) bad to do this if it is 1) unnecessary complexity or 2) beyond ones ability to implement the transfer correctly.

Comment: It's a count, the "permits" are just conceptual. The count is threadsafe. Look at the source code and read the API doc.

Comment: @StephenC I think in the vast majority of cases it would be unnecessary complexity. Also regardless of whether its "beyond ones ability" or not, implementing "clever" solutions is a surefire way to have a *future maintainer* unintentionally break everything. So yes, perhaps a slight oversimplification but he's asking about the fundamentals of a core concurrency mechanism; it *should be* made as easy to reason about as possible.

Comment: @Michael I am passing a callback to external code through an interface, i cannot expect full, 100% thread-safety when i do that, and i want to know if it is needed for the callback call to be on the same thread that sent off that callback

Comment: @Shadowjonathan What's wrong with `acquire(); callback(); release();` ?

Comment: @Michael I was finding out if there was any, my experience with Golang taught me about thread ownership with Mutexes, and this paranoia carried over when I started doing java concurrency.

Comment: @Shadowjonathan Well, just remember that just because you *can* do something doesn't mean that you *should*.

Comment: @Michael i know that, i'll keep that in mind, but the module i am designing will probably be used from Android to Desktop java applications, each of them have different implementations of low-level stuff like Downloads and web requests, in android it will work differently than JavaFX, so that's why i'm letting those be implemented in an interface, and wait till it's done through semaphores.

Comment: You can use a `Semaphore` as a substitute for a `Lock`, but that doesn't mean that a semaphore is a kind of lock. Semaphores are abstract objects that you can use in [a variety of different ways](https://www.amazon.com/Little-Book-SEMAPHORES-2nd-Concurrency/dp/1441418687) to coordinate the activities of two or more different threads. In some useful semaphore-based patterns, the semaphore permits will be released in one thread and acquired in another.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is note on the [Javadoc about `release()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release())

> There is no requirement that a thread that releases a permit must have
>   acquired that permit by calling acquire(). Correct usage of a
>   semaphore is established by programming convention in the application.

So yes. You can do.